# Custom List in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list

New to SharePoint so giving it a crack.  I created a custom list by importing a spreadsheet.  Some time ago, I tried to delete it but I believe I just deleted the webpage used to display the content because when I click on the name (CCItest) of the list, I get the

> 404 - Webpage not found.

But I can't select the list name CCItest to remove it because as it is, it is of no use.

Can anyone advise how I can remove this list entry name?  The Recycle Bin contain nothing.  Is the data from the imported spreadsheet still stored?

Can I create a new custom list with the same name, import a spreadsheet and hope it overwrites the old stuff and move on?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the list using [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee806878.aspx#section2):

```
$web = get-spweb -Identity http://spsiteurl
$list = $web.lists["list name"]
$list.AllowDeletion = $true
$list.Update()
$list.Delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a farm administrator or a developer with your own dev environment, chances are that you don't have permissions to log on to the server and run PowerShell.

As a regular SharePoint end user you may have access to SharePoint Designer, though. Open the site in SPD. Here you can navigate to the list and delete it.